# a variation on set cover

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

The set cover optimization problem is: given a universe `U` and a set `S` of subsets of `U` (i.e. S \subsetof 2^U), find the minimal subset `C` of `S` such that the union of its elements is `U`. Known to be NP-hard.

The variation I am interested in is, given the same things (`U` and `S`), find the minimal subset `C` of `S` such that `C` is a cover, and also for some (unspecified) element `u` in `U`, all sets in `S` containing `u` are in `C`.

The problem I'm applying this to is: given a set of symptoms I'm seeing (`U`), I have potential causes for these problems (`S` - each element of `S` is corresponds to a "cause" of potentially multiple symptoms). I want the least number of causes that can cause all the symptoms I'm seeing, and I also want to have the result that removing all of these "cause"s will also cause at least one symptom to be solved.

Does anyone have any good ideas on whether this is any easier than the original problem?

**EDIT to include solution (incorporating comments)**

It is at least as hard as set cover.

`SetCover(U,S)` can be solved via `SetCoverNew(U + {w}, S + {{w}})` with `w` being an element not in `U` and `+` denoting set union.

Any solution of the given SetCoverNew instance must include the set `{w}` (otherwise it is not a set cover of `U + {w}`).

It is claimed that a solution of the `SetCover(U,S)` is `X = SetCoverNew(...) \ {{w}}`. First, `X` must be a cover of `U`, otherwise `X + {{w}}` cannot be a cover of `U + {w}`. Secondly, `X` must be a minimal cover of `U`, otherwise, `SetCover(U,S) + {{w}}` is a cover of lower cardinality than `SetCoverNew(...)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is also NP-Hard since we can solve the original set cover problem using this one.
Suppose we are supplied with an algorithm that solve this new problem (called `SetCoverNew`).

Here is an algorithm to solve SetCover.

```
SetCover(U, S)
  1. build new universe U1 = {U + w} (w is not in `U`, and `+` means `union`).
  2. build the new set S1 = S + {w}.
  3. result = SetCoverNew(U1, S1, w)
  4. return result - {w}.
```

**EDIT**
sorry, I did not see the `unspecified u` let me think it over :)

Comment: +1, but I don't understand "(while w is not in U) while + is union" in your step 1.

Comment: @Lijie - This is not exactly what you asked since my answer is for specified `u`.

Comment: @j_random_hacker: What I mean is that `U1` is a new set that contains `U` and one more element `w` that does not belong to `U`

Comment: @Itay: I understand that from the phrase "build new universe U1 = {U + w}" alone.  But I can't parse the rest of that line!

Comment: no it answers. because `u` is not specified in the problem. the answer actually matches my intentions, which is why I love the answer.

Comment: @j_random_hacker: I think Itay just means that w should not be in U, and that he is using `+` to denote unions.

Comment: @lijie: Ah thanks.  @Itay, could I suggest changing it to "(w is not in U, and '+' means 'union')".

Comment: @Itay: okay I see what you mean! `SetCoverNew` specifies `u`. However, that is okay, because the only set in `S` which contains `u` is `{w}`, so `{w}` must be in the solution set, and this solution set also has all the elements in `S` containing `w` already, so that part of the problem is fulfilled. Hence, the other sets in the solution set solve `SetCover(U,S)`. Does this argument work?

Comment: @Lijie: In my solution `SetCoverNew` gets `w` as parameter and `w` does not belong to `U`. From your question it sounds like `w` can be any element from `U`.

Comment: @Itay: I've edited my question to incorporate your solution (modified so that it doesn't require `w` as a parameter). Does it make sense to you or is it flawed?

Comment: @Lijie: `SetCoverNew` as I presented it can be used to solve `SetCover` what I am not sure is that `SetCoverNew` solves your problem.

Comment: The modified `SetCoverNew` (which doesn't take the `w` parameter), which solves my problem, should also solve `SetCover`, and the means of solving `SetCover` is the same as how your solution states, I think..

Comment: @Lijie: but the modified `SetCoverNew` uses `w` that is not in `U` and in your original question it is in `U`.

Comment: @Itay: Isn't the point to describe a way of solving `SetCover` using `SetCoverNew`? We're just defining a `U'` and `S'` to give to `SetCoverNew` so that it solves `SetCover(U,S)`, right?

Comment: @Lijie: Right, but... `SetCoverNew` does not solve your problem. so it does not mean that you problem is in the same complexity class as `SetCover` (It doesn't mean the opposite either).

Comment: @Itay: I think the modified `SetCoverNew` is defined to be the oracle that solves the modified set cover problem, so it does solve my problem... and since `SetCoverNew` can be used to solve `SetCover`, it is at least NP-hard. But everything that is at least NP-hard is NP-hard (due to the definition of NP-hard), so it is NP-hard.. I think..

Comment: If `SetCoverNew` solves your original problem I agree, maybe I did not understand your original problem.

Comment: like in the second line of your answer, we just define `SetCoverNew` to solve the problem; it's just that `SetCoverNew` should only take 2 parameters, `U` and `S`, rather than `U`, `S` and `w`.

Comment: And how would you call `SetCoverNew` to solve your original problem?

Comment: `SetCoverNew(U,S)` would solve my original problem (which is a derivative of the set cover problem)... the procedure in your answer solves `SetCover(U,S)` given an oracle that solves `SetCoverNew`

Answer (score 0):

Some time ago I looked at the problem of working out what was going wrong in a telecommunications network, given various reports from the nodes. The requirement was to assign a few root causes that could account for possibly large numbers of alarms (alarm storms). There are a number of (very expensive) products out there, taking a wide variety of approaches.

I decided that the problem was so theoretically intractable that the only practical way to approach it was to arrange to gather data so as to make the problem of finding out where problems started trivial (e.g. to make sure each node reported how it thought it was doing and whether it through the nodes it was relying on were doing their jobs). Given that, I reckon you should be able to assign most alarms to root causes just by subtracting out the alarms you expect to be produced by the root causes your instrumentation tells you are obviously there.

I don't know what your problem domain is, but I suggest that you take some time to see if gathering the right data will make diagnosis easier.

Comment: yes, this is actually the main purpose that i wanted to look at this stuff. the problem of assigning fewest root causes can be solved via set cover. in my case, i wanted the additional criteria of having the set of alarms change, should i fix all the root causes identified. the benefit of knowing that it is NP-hard is that i can rest happy knowing that using an approximation algorithm is the best i can do, practically (for original set cover, the greedy algorithm does well and is fast).